# Port Collision on port 80

Tags: apache, vagrant, homestead

I restarted my iMac for the first time in quite a while (something like 2 weeks). When I attempted to restart my homestead box via `homestead up`, I got this error:

```
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 80 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current projects Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding.
```

I have no other virtual boxes running. I ran `sudo lsof -i :80` and got the following list:

```
COMMAND    PID        USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google     391 jamesspence   85u  IPv4 0xe9a8a2357c33587      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.84:49665->ord08s12-in-f28.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google     391 jamesspence   86u  IPv4 0xe9a8a235682a727      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.84:49666->ord31s22-in-f6.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google     391 jamesspence  249u  IPv4 0xe9a8a234f7d0247      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.84:49215->ec2-54-82-95-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
httpd     1240        root    5u  IPv6 0xe9a8a234f7e08a7      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1241        _www    5u  IPv6 0xe9a8a234f7e08a7      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

The "Google" processes appears to be Chrome, as killing it kills my browser. Apache2 also appears to to be running on this port as well. So, halting it with `sudo apachectl stop` seems to help. When I do that, I get past the port collision stage. However, then my virtual box hangs up at forming a connection:

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

I'm at my wit's end here. Less than 24 hours ago, my vagrant box was running just fine, no issues. I have no idea where to proceed from here. Does anybody have any idea of what I should do next?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by booting in safe boot (holding Shift while initially booting), and then restarting. After that, I was still getting the `connection timeout` issue, but just starting and stopping the virtualbox manually fixed that, and now everything's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

What your first message meant was that your port forwarding was invalid, because it used the 80 port on your host machine (so your Mac), and this port is used like you identified it by Chrome and else. What you should try is to put in your Vagrantfile a correct forwarding, like this :

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080 #http-apache
```

And then access your virtual machine using `localhost:8080` and not the default `localhost:80` (which is the same as `localhost`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem though, is that it's getting to that guest port, attempting to forward it, and throwing an error. Changing the host port doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Could you share your Vagrantfile ? The answer lies there I believe, because your solution seems a little bit hacky and not a real one.

Comment: I'm using [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead), which has a pre-configured VagrantFile that I haven't touched.